# VS2012 "Add as link" functionality for a certain block of code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

I would like to use MS VS2012's add as link functionality, meant for files, but instead for a certain block of code.

I've got a solution with lots of projects. I am creating a unit testing project that will house all the algorithms that exist in the other projects in the solution. I can copy over all the algorithms I want to test into a file in the new unit testing project, however I am also looking for a way to automatically update the code in the test file if say the code in the other projects updates. It is almost as if I want to create a reference to a code chunk in VS.

If no such functionality exists is there some sort of script I could create that updates the code in the test project every time I build?

EDIT:The reason I can not have testing code within the projects themselves is because the other projects in the solution are .NET Microframework projects and the .NET Microframework does not support the use of c# attributes which are being used with the NUnit testing framework. Hence the reason I can not have any test code within those projects. However, there are some algorithms in the driver files of the .Net MF projects that I would like to be able to test and these algorithms are independent of the project type, so I am looking for a way to keep this code in sync so that if any changes are made to the algorithm within the .Net MF projects the same respective change is made within the unit testing project without the need for manual copying.

EDIT: In the simplest terminology all I am looking for is some sort of script I can run to copy over certain code blocks from one project file to another project file.

Comment: What's wrong for you by having your own library and just calling the methods, which would be built into and attached to the projects from assembly?

Comment: This would be a poor way of testing code. Why not just call the code from your test project?

Comment: Isn't this what assemblies are for?

Comment: Sounds like either your infrastrucure is messed up or you didn't understood the role of solutions and references.

Comment: @Bob Horn. Why is that a poor way?

Comment: And why +1 for "Poor way" mentioning comment? That does not have a sense.

Comment: @Agat Because there is no reason to make a copy of the code and then have the headache of keeping it in sync. See the second part of my comment: Why not just call the code from your test project? That's typically how testing is done.

Comment: @BobHorn, edit made to clarify problem.

Comment: @user1084113. If you add/update something you should write "update:" or "edit:" and add your changes then not to cofuse existent readers.

Comment: @user1084113 Why would you need test code in the micro framework project itself? Why not have your test code in a test project and simply call the other project?

Comment: Well, if I would have had a million, that would be also perfect. But I don't. Because, that's tough and there are many other (much more significant) problems in the area to solve for software development tools companies than just "to do everything perfect for certain custom calls". Plus, if you have such problems with different frameworks etc, that means, you should consider reworking (or rethinking of your testing environment/approaches paradigm).

Comment: @user1084113. Plus, I still don't get how is the problem with Attributes mentioned would caused you to use your approach chosen?

Comment: @Agat - auto-magically updating unit tests due to algorithm change is very unusual because changes in the code should either not impact tests (internal details) OR require explicit change of the test (algorithm/API changes). That is why it is "poor way" - most people will be confused about this behavior.

Comment: Well, you just trying to play fair with evil face. he he You can not sit on both chairs. So, you should either to decide to write a good-quality code to reuse it everywhere (like any testing frameworks do) (like implementing some method "GetGreenColorForFurtherTesting" (which always would return only green one, but not red)) without any dramatic changes in future. Or you are just not worrying about copying your code block every time you need (as you might need to correct that "GetGreen..." code to "GetLightGreen..." one for special tests).

Comment: @BobHorn, I can not call the projects from my Test project because those .Net MF projects are required to run on actual hardware. I would just like to test some of the logic in the driver files.

Comment: Plus, let's imagine the mentioned references-to-the-code-blocks would be possible to use. So, what's the difference on that from assemblies? The same way if you change the source -- the same way it reflects changes in any place it was used. (Even more, you then just even can not have any versioning of those code blocks!)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. I am not asking to automatically change the unit tests I just need some sort of script that will copy over code from one project to another.

Comment: @user1084113 Have you heard of MFUnit? http://blog.duc.as/2012/04/05/unit-testing-and-the-net-micro-framework/

Comment: @user1084113. You really should rethink your approach, I would rather advice to create another question like "What is the best way to organize my reusable code for Micro .NET Framework Tests projects?" instead of building a bicycle (especially, of wrong construction).

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem where different parts of the same source code file were shared between different projects. Here is a fix that worked for me.

Suppose the source file File1.cs contains four methods, two of which are used by ProjA and two are used by ProjB, where ProjA and ProjB are different projects inside a Visual Studio solution.

To keep just one copy of File1.cs, use conditional compile symbols, e.g. PROJ_A and PROJ_B for the two projects. Put the methods used by ProjA under conditional compilation symbol `#if PROJ_A` and put the methods used by ProjB under conditional compilation symbol `#if PROJ_B`. Then add File1.cs as linked file to both projects and make sure that corresponding conditional compilation symbols are set on those projects.

If this is what you were looking for, let me know if you get any problems implementing it.

Comment: The developers worlds is going crazy! People are trying to transform C# into C++ (if not even to C) just because of... "I don't know how to do it right".

Comment: -1 ...because even though the suggested answer can rather solve the problem literally, I would really did not recommend to go with such way of code organizing.